# GruntFile automated deployment using ssh (Windows)

Tags: javascript, git, ssh, gruntjs, public-key-encryption

I am trying to set up a GruntFile.js file to automate the process of logging on to my personal website's server via ssh and pulling the latest version of the git repo. The relevant part of my grunt file looks like this:

```
sshconfig: {
    portfolioServer: {
    host: 'mySite.com',
    username: 'root',
    agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
    }
},

sshexec:{
    deploy:{
    command: [
        'cd portfolio',
        'git pull'
    ].join(' && ')
    },
    options:{
    config: 'portfolioServer'
    }
},
```

However, when I run the associated task (I named it "grunt deploy"). I get the following error.

```
Running "sshexec:deploy" (sshexec) task
Warning: Connection :: error :: Error: Authentication failure. Available authentication methods: publickey,password Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

My understanding is that this error means that I have not set up the public/private ssh keys correctly. However, I have already gone through the process of setting up public/private keys.I am already able to run the following command through git bash and log in successfully:

```
ssh root@mySite.com
```

I have searched online for this problem and it seems like it might have something to do with process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK not behaving in git bash on windows in the same way that it might be expected to be have in a native linux distribution.

What further steps in my setup do I have to take in order to make this deployment configuration work?